# HTML spacing issue - all browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have built this sample gallery, but for some reason there is vertical spacing between the images which I want to remove. I can not see any where that will remove the spacing:

http://alexconner.co.uk/gallery_test/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a problem with the linebreaks between the li tags

just try that:

```
<li>img1</li><li>img2</li>
```

instead of pulling every single tag on every single line